# How to create a SOAP service for consume on TFS alert

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, tfs

I want to create a c# services and I want that when some file was checkin my services should be execute:
I did that but is not calling

checkinListener.asmx

```
    public class JenkinsListener : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    static DateTime lastTime;
    static  System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    static  int count;
    [WebMethod]
    public void Checkin()
    {
        //I want to execute that
    }
```

And I put that on TFS
[image]

But the code is not executed

Answer (score 0):

That code is not when close...

```
Public Sub Notify(ByVal eventXml As String, ByVal tfsIdentityXml As String, ByVal SubscriptionInfo As TeamFoundation.SubscriptionInfo)
```

You need something that implements the end point above.

https://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#RELEASE/v1.3/RDdotNet.TeamFoundation/Services/INotificationService.vb

Here is an example I built for TFS 2008.